# Pygame button won't work on press/only on hover

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to have an onclick button print a check and run my pencil function. At the moment if I hover over the Box sprite.. it will run the print and pencil function. It should be ONCLICK it runs those 2. Can anyone help me out? Thanks! (this should be all relevant code, if you need more please let me know :)

```
class Box(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((35, 30))
    self.image = self.image.convert()
    self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = 25
    self.rect.centery = 505
    self.dx = 10
    self.dy = 10

while keepGoing:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keepGoing = False
        box = Box()
        allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(box)   
        allSprites.draw(screen)

        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            x,y = event.pos
            if box.rect.collidepoint(x,y) and pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:                      
                print("collide works")
                pencil(background,clock,keepGoing,screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not checking for mouse clicks, but rather mouse movement.

If you want to be testing for a click on your box, change condition to check for `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or `MOUSEBUTTONUP` events (depending on what part of the click you want to react to), rather than `MOUSEMOTION` events.

There are some other issues with your code though. For instance, you're creating your Box and Group after every event. Probably you want to just create them once, before going into the game loop (this will both make more sense and perform better).

Comment: Sigh... Thank you. I feel pretty dumb right now. All the examples/tutorials etc. I've seen.. make it seem like you check for a mouse motion.. then check for the mouse event that happens (ie. mousedown). Thanks again.